# Get TextView for edit in other class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, findviewbyid

I created TextView programmatically, how I can get my TextView for changing text?

**Code**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle){
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        var layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

        var relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layout.AddView(relativeLayout);

        TextView textViewTime = new TextView(this);
        textViewTime.Text = "00:00:00";
        textViewTime.Id = 1;
        relativeLayout.AddView(textViewTime);
        ...
}

public class MyScrollView : HorizontalScrollView

    {
        ...

        protected override void OnScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt)
        {                
             TextView tv = (TextView)FindViewById(1); //returns null
             ...
        }
}
```

Comment: use layout.findViewById(id) and reply.

Comment: OK, but I how I can get layout in OnScrollChanged method ?

Comment: pass the layout as a parameter..

Comment: I created static LinearLayout and use it

Comment: Yes, It works with static LinearLayout, I can use it at another class